# PHP Fatal Error, Uncaught Error in my Site

Tags: php, pdo

**Hello Guys!**

I have a problem regarding to my PHP Site.

So basically its a site where users can login, they need to fill in there names,surnames,where they live and Email.

then the data will be saved in an MyAdmin Database, there i have created sites, which show all users, so when you click on a button all users are shown.
Also we made a Random Update Site.
And last thing, we need to make another update site where you can update data from every user whatever you want.

This is a school project, and I already asked my teacher but he gets mad every time so I am really pissed and I don't want to ask this fella.
Alright I will copy the Code in here:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user', 'root', '');
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = $id");
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user', 'root', '');
    if (!isset($name)) {
        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        $Vorname = $_POST['Vorname'];
        $Nachname = $_POST['Nachname'];
        $Postleitzahl = $_POST['Postleitzahl'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Menge = $_POST['Menge'];
        $Ratenzahlung = $_POST['Ratenzahlung'];
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql = "UPDATE user SET Vorname = '$Vorname', Nachname = '$Nachname', Postleitzahl = '$Postleitzahl', Email = '$Email', Menge = '$Menge', Ratenzahlung = '$Ratenzahlung',  WHERE ID = $id");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Aktualisieren erfolgreich.";
    require_once("showv2.php");
}
if (!isset($Vorname)) {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Bookmark Update </title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="edit.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" value=<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>>
                <input type="text" name="Vorname" style="width:50px" value=<?php echo $row["Vorname"]; ?>>
                <input type="text" name="Nachname" value=<?php echo $row["Nachname"]; ?>>
                <input type="number" name="Postleitzahl" value=<?php echo $row["Postleitzahl"]; ?>>
                <input type="text" name="Email" style="width:50px" value=<?php echo $row["Email"]; ?>>
                <input type="number" name="Menge" style="width:50px" value=<?php echo $row["Menge"]; ?>>
                <input type="text" name="Ratenzahlung" style="width:50px" value=<?php echo $row["Ratenzahlung"]; ?>>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Data">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

and here the Error
Fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on
>   boolean in
>   C:\Users\schueler\Desktop\website\Registrierformular\edit.php:6 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\schueler\Desktop\website\Registrierformular\edit.php on line
>   6

Thank you guys, also note, I am an completely beginner, as I have no clue of javascript or other types of programming languages, as we skipped all between and jumped from MS Access to PHP and so you can imagine its pretty hard to keep up!

Thanks for your Answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is failing.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = $id");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

$id is a string in the above query.

The correct query should be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Furthermore, in your update query you are using prepared statements wrong.

This is how you should use them.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user', 'root', '');
    if (!isset($name)) {
        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        $Vorname = $_POST['Vorname'];
        $Nachname = $_POST['Nachname'];
        $Postleitzahl = $_POST['Postleitzahl'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Menge = $_POST['Menge'];
        $Ratenzahlung = $_POST['Ratenzahlung'];
    }


    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user SET Vorname = ?, Nachname = ?, Postleitzahl = ?, Email = ?, Menge = ?, Ratenzahlung = ?  WHERE ID = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$Vorname,$Nachname,$Postleitzahl,$Email,$Menge,$Ratenzahlung,$id]);
    echo "Aktualisieren erfolgreich.";
    require_once("showv2.php");
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! so the whole thing seems to work, but i think you didnt quite understood what i need to do, alright ill explain, so i should be able to show all users, and then next to all names, addresses etc. should be an edit button, if i try your solution it just goes directly to the site where i can edit these things, and if ill type something in ill get errors

Comment: one thing I should note is, that my whole programm worked before, until, I edited it with css, I editet the homepage with dropdown menus in CSS and after that it didnt worked, I tried to undo it but i did too many steps before, so i have no clue whats wrong but iam looking forward to solve it!

Comment: The error you getting is solved by this.. this has nothing to do with css and you menion